# Changing img tag src value using javascript with the Django framework

Tags: javascript, django

I am trying to load a random image from a dictionary on page load using Javascript.
This is the HTML

```
  <div class="img-container">
    {% load static %}
    <img id="qimage" src="{% static '' %}"></img>
  </div>
```

So basically I want to change the src to a random generated image src from dictionary on page load:
this is the Javascript:

```
window.onload = function(){ 
  var image = document.getElementById("qimage");
  let src = getRandomImage();
  image.setAttribute("src",src);
}
```

And this is the generate random image function:

```
function getRandomImage(){
 var keys = Object.keys(dict);
 var index = getRandomInt(0,keys.length);
 var selection = keys[index];
 var image = dict[selection][0];
 return image;
}
```

and lastly this is the dictionary:

```
var dict = {
 "barrackStreet":["{% static 'images/hard/bstreet.jpg' %}",{"lat":51.893897,"lng":-8.477632}],
 "GrandParade":["{% static 'images/hard/gparade.jpg' %}",{"lat":51.893897,"lng":-8.477632}],
 "PatricksHill":["{% static 'images/hard/phill.jpg' %}",{"lat":51.893897,"lng":-8.477632}],
};
```

Comment: Hi @Jeff, what issue are you facing?
getRandomInt is missing on description, but if I replace it by `var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length);` on getRandomImage function it returns the string expected.

Comment: Welcom on stackoverflow :) Can you explain what exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you move that logic to Python/Django? In that way you won't need to write JS code. Note this will only work if your `dict` variable has a fixed value and not randomly generated from JS side.

You can use Django's a built-in filter [random](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#random) to randomly choose a value from a list. Make a list containing your image directories like this:

```
dict = {
 "barrackStreet":["{% static 'images/hard/bstreet.jpg' %}",{"lat":51.893897,"lng":-8.477632}],
 "GrandParade":["{% static 'images/hard/gparade.jpg' %}",{"lat":51.893897,"lng":-8.477632}],
 "PatricksHill":["{% static 'images/hard/phill.jpg' %}",{"lat":51.893897,"lng":-8.477632}],
}
img_list = [v[0] for k,v in dict.items()]
```

Then pass that from your view to your template and in your template render it like this:

```
<img id="qimage" src="{{ img_list|random }}"></img>
```

Comment: Okay thank you so much I didn't know about Django's random filter, this is very helpful :)